# Slow query performance with Partitioned tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I was reading articles about partition tables and got confused as in whether it is a boon or bane. I do understand that partition is meant for large amount of datasets. but here is my confusion:
Lets assume that there is a table:

```
Orders(Orderid,Custid,Orderdate,Shipperid)
```

and its has huge amount of data; well enough to justify the partitioning. There are select queries done on every column of this table; many queries having joins with other tables.
If I partition the table on the basis of OrderId; will other queries based on other columns become slow? 
Will the join queries involving column other than OrderId column become slow?

Will appreciate any guidance!! Thanks

Comment: You don't want to partition a table on `OrderID` column if this is a unique identifier. Based on your table structure you shall partition on `OrderDate` column. You can partition by year or by month, depends on how large your table is. This will allow SQL server to query data only in date range needed.

Comment: @AndLev : Thank you, but what I am confused with is that would not it effect other select queries involving other columns; other than OrderDate? I have never done that; so I dont know how it would impact. Just want to make sure before doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have two tables with the same schema and the same data.  Both are clustered on OrderID.  One of these tables is also partitioned by OrderID.  Sometimes access is keyed by OrderID and sometimes not.

Lookups for a single OrderID may be faster against the partitioned table if you have sufficient data to force multiple levels in your index BTree.  This is because there is one BTree per partition.  Lookups for a range of OrderIDs will, in general, be faster because of partition elimination - SQL Server will only access those partitions needed to satisfy the query.

Lookups or scans on other keys will be no different.

Partitioning also allows swap in and swap out of a whole partition which can save hours in a daily load / delete cycle.

Comment: creating a new database to try that before doing anything on production. Any link that you would recommend for reading about partitioning. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user2438237 - When I started out I found the [MS Technet articles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) useful.  Since then I've found [this](http://www.brentozar.com/sql/table-partitioning-resources/) round-up with many links to follow.